# Generator find the coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have this : $$6a(n)=-2^n+a(n+1), a(1)=4$$

what is the coefficient  of this ? I beleive 1) 5*6/4  what do you think?

1)$ (5*6)/4 $

2)$ (17*6)/4 $

3)$  (15*6)/4 $

4)$  (31*6)/4 $

Comment: What is  "coffit" ?

Comment: coefficient Ι  will edited

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by the coefficient. Which coefficient? Something related to the sequence?

Comment: I think you wish to ask the coefficient of a term? Perhaps $a(3)$ or something like that?

Comment: @MattiP. I mean I have https://www.wolframalpha.com/  if you write 6a(n)=−2^n+a(n+1),a(1)=4 then you will have  a(n) = 2^(n - 2) (3^(n + 1) - 1) . I have those solutions 1) , 2) ,3) ,4) which one has with this a(n) = 2^(n - 2) (3^(n + 1) - 1)  the same

Answer (score 1):

So let's solve the recurrence $a_{n+1}-6a_n = 2^n$ with the initial condition $a_1=4$.

The homogeneous recurrence $a_{n+1}-6a_n=0$ has solution $a_n = A 6^n$ and imposing the inhomogeneous RHS you should end up with $a_n = A\cdot 6^n + B\cdot 2^n$, and now imposing $a_1=4$ can solve for $B$.

Then you have the whole sequence, and the answer will depend on what you mean by "coefficient."

---

**UPDATE**

I am getting the same output from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6a%5Bn%5D%3Da%5Bn%2B1%5D-2%5En+and+a%5B1%5D%3D4), indeed $a_n = 2^{n-2}\left(3^{n+1}-1\right)$. I still don't understand what is meant here by "coefficient." Perhaps the intent is to rewrite
$$
a_n = 2^{n-2}\left(3^{n+1}-1\right) = \frac{3 \cdot 6^n - 2^n}{4},
$$
then the coefficient of $6^n$ is $3/4$ and the coefficient of $2^n$ is $-1/4$?

Comment: check my comment

Comment: I mean I have wolframalpha.com if you write 6a(n)=−2^n+a(n+1),a(1)=4 then you will have a(n) = 2^(n - 2) (3^(n + 1) - 1) . I have those solutions 1) , 2) ,3) ,4) which one has with this a(n) = 2^(n - 2) (3^(n + 1) - 1) the same

Comment: @maikkain see update, still not clear. The expression "coefficeint" is very ambiguous in this context

Comment: thecoefficient is lets say we have 2x^2 .I mean coefficient the 2,what is in front of x. In what you wrote  $$(3⋅6^n−2^n) /4$$ I want somehow to find one of those 1) ,2),3),4)

Comment: @maikkain the normal use of the word "coefficient" does not really result in any of those 4 expressions.